# Call an external app's view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an installed app called 'publications' and I am trying to call the 'publications' views from within my Django project. I keep getting the following error:

```
from citations_app import views as citations_app_views
   ImportError: No module named citations_app
```

So, I can't "load" the external app's views and, if I could, am not sure if I'm calling it correctly. I'm trying to use my "display_info" view function to get a list of data and then pass that data to the external app's "list_view" view function. 
Here is my citations.py view file:

```
from django.db.models import get_app
citations_app = get_app("publications")
from citations_app import views as citations_app_views
from citations_app_views import list as list_view

def display_info(request):
    citations = request.GET.getlist('citation-selection')
    return list_view(request, citations)
```

Any idea why I get the import error and if I am calling the "list_view" view function correctly?
Thank you!!

DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:

```
MyApp1/
  models/ 
    publications.py
    citations.py
    items.py
  views/
    publications.py
    citations.py
    items.py
MyApp2/
Publications/ (not physically present at this location but installed as part of requirements.txt file)
```

I am working in views/items.py.

Comment: It seems you don't have any app called citations_app... Did you add citations_app in your settings.py in `INSTALLED_APPS`??

Comment: Please show your directory structure. Have you really got an app called "citations_app", rather than just "citations"? And note that the line after that makes no sense at all, you should remove it.

Comment: The installed app is actually "publications". I'm trying to import "publications" by calling get_app("publications") and saving that as citations_app. (I have already included the app "publications" in INSTALLED_APPS)...

Comment: Why are you using `get_app()`—a private API that has been deprecated—instead of Python's regular import mechanism (`from publications import views as citations_app_views`)?

Comment: I'm using get_app() because I have files named publications.py in both the views and models directories (unrelated to the installed publications app) and I couldn't get those regular imports to work. I think it's a naming issue but couldn't figure it out. So, citations_app = get_app("publications") works in my models/items.py file to import & use the models correctly but it doesn't work in my views/items.py to get the views. In views/items.py, if I try `from publications import views as citations_app_views`, I get an `ImportError: cannot import name views`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `get_app()`, you just need to get your directory structure and import paths working properly.

It sounds like you're saying that the problem is that the local `publications.py` is shadowing the `publications` app? You must be on Python 2, then, since this ambiguity is no longer possible in Python 3. To remove the ambiguity in Python 2, add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the top of the file. Once you do that, `from publications import ...` will always refer to the top-level app. To access the local `publications.py` you'll use either `from .publications import ...` or `from myapp1.models.publications import ...`.

See [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) if you want to learn more about the absolute / relative import issue.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!
Yes, I am using Python 2.7: I knew it wasn't 'grabbing' the correct '"publications" but I couldn't understand why, since the external publications app is in a different directory. Wow, days spent trying to figure this out- thank you!